# Why won't my ReactJS page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a practice web app using ReactJS but I can't even load this simple test to see if things will work so I can move on & create the app.

Here's the `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My website</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the `index.js` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Testing.</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Edit Below:

Here's the `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My website</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the `index.js` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>hiii</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Comment: what error messages are you getting? any on the page or in the console? including those will usually help you get an answer quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works but I think you are not loading properly. How are you opening your application? Are you just opening the HTML file? Does your URL look like `file:///path-to-your-html-file.html`?

Using file path did not work for me; so, I would suggest you to use a web server to handle your files. One easy way to manage this is to run NodeJS [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server.) application. Just run `npm install -g http-server`. Then, go to your application directory in the terminal and execute `http-server`.

Comment: Thank you, it works!  I was using the Sublime IDE at first & it works fine.  But then I decided to switch to the Atom IDE.  When I switched to the Atom IDE, it stopped working.  How can that be?

Comment: Check out the error output. I tested your app in Atom and it worked fine. To be honest, if I were you, I would have learned how to set it up with webpack. Much easier to maintain IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script for index.js after your example div in body!

Answer (score 0):

Like /u/Peter Qiu said, You will need to place `<script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>` after the `<div id="example"></div>` element for it to work.

Also, you'll have to add in the babel transpiler in order for your babel code to work in the browser:

https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-core

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>`

You can add it in the head section after your react/react-dom dependencies.

---

Also, to run the react app correctly, you'll need to run the index.html file through a static server. Here's a simple one to get started with:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Opening the index.html file into your browser (by double-clicking) will return a Cross-origin request error.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.  I'll post what I did in my original post.

Comment: that's odd. I tried it on my computer and it works fine. May I know what folder structure you're using for your project? is the `index.js` file in the same directory as `index.html`?

Comment: Yeah it is, it's all in the same folder.

Comment: How are you viewing your html file, via static server or just opening it in your browser? I opened mine using node http-server 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

when i opened the index.html file in the browser (double clicking the file and opening it in chrome) nothing happens.

Comment: just opening it in my browser.

Comment: got your problem then. you'll need to run it in some sort of static server in order for the code to work (i stated in my previous comment) . i'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133846/discussion-between-chompy-and-dommmm).